# AttributeError: module 'pyspark.dbutils' has no attribute 'fs'

Tags: python, databricks

`AttributeError` when attempting to transfer files from `dbfs` filestore in DataBricks to a local directory.

```
import pyspark.dbutils as pdbutils

pdbutils.fs.cp("/dbfs/Data/file1.csv", "/Users/Downloads/")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3378, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<command-1495140876495465>", line 4, in <module>
    pdbutils.fs.cp("/dbfs/Usage-Data/df_tx_0106_2022.csv", "/Users/keval/Downloads/")
AttributeError: module 'pyspark.dbutils' has no attribute 'fs'
```

Comment: where do you run this?

Comment: @AlexOtt In the terminal on Databricks cluster.

Comment: in terminal or in the notebook?

Comment: @AlexOtt I tried it on the notebook as well as the web terminal.